# ng-Cordova navigator.geolocation stops the application after giving the location access

Tags: angular, cordova, cross-domain

I have created an Angular project and wrapped it with cordova to have a cross-domain web application. My 
home screen is loading a Map after seeking location access. It was working fine but suddenly after allowing location access my application is not running anymore unless I tap few times on the screen or opening a different component and coming back to home screen starts loading again. This is working fine on browser but don't know what is causing this behavior in android.
Here I am adding few screens to explain my problem better.

This is my promise to get the navigator.geolocation[image]

This is my HomeComponent [image: d]

**Android Application View**

**Asking Permission**
[image]

**After Access it stops responding unlikely browser**
[image]

**After tapping on screen several times, going to different components and coming back brings my Map** [image]

Answer (score 0):

You used it as a promise, so it will just work the first time. If you want to get the data more than once, you have to subscribe to it. Inseat of `getCurrentPosition()` use `watchPosition()`

For more info take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

Comment: But it works fine on my browser since I am in the testing phase I can work along with the Promise(since called automatically each time the position of the device changes). Right now, my concern is why it gets stuck after allowing the location access.